# Efficient way to transform non english and non numeric values in impala

Tags: regex, special-characters, impala

I have a table that contains over 3M records.
One of the attributes includes sometimes English letters and numbers (including spaces between them and signs like -) and sometimes includes other values such as different languages such as Chinese, Russian letters, spaces, special characters etc.
I would to keep the each the attribute value as is in case of English letters and numbers including minus or legitimate characters between them. For the special characters and non English (as well as space) - I would like to transfer them into same value such as all the same names in Chinese will be transformed into SC1 (Special characters 1) the next special characters will be transformed into SC2 etc. What is the most efficient way to do it?

Here is an example for Table (TB1):

```
+-----+-----------+-------------+--------- 
| ID  | Att1      |  New Att1   | Some more attributes...
+-----+-----------+-------------+--------- 
|  1  | ABC-1     | ABC-1       |
|  2  | 中国      | SC1         |
|  3  | кириллица | SC2         |
|  4  | 中国      | SC1         |
|  5  | кириллица | SC2         |
|  6  | BCD EFH   | BCD EFH     |
|  7  | (Space)   | SC3         |
....
```

Answer (score 1):

A common way to achieve such thing is to write a UDF doing language detection. You can resort to [cld2](https://github.com/CLD2Owners/cld2) in case if you like to develop one. Here is an [example](https://github.com/cloudera/impala-udf-samples) of how to develop an impala udf.

However, if those 3M records are the only corpus you need to process, I'd suggest just pulling them out of impala, transforming them using script languages and putting them back.